# linqpad 4.0 and code only

Tags: entity-framework, entity, linqpad

How can I use linqpad with code only in ef 4.

I mean how to reference metadata when there is no edmx file?

Answer (score 2):

I think LINQPad will need to be updated to support this feature. Have you tried the [latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx)? There's no reason LINQPad *couldn't* support code only, but it would need specific support for it. That said, I don't think LINQPad reads the EDMX directly; rather, I think it uses the generated code.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (4/29/11) there is a new [LINQPad beta (v4.34.2)](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) that will work with EF 4.1 Code First.